# Not Getting All Results from soup.findAll()

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have found this table on a website (https://covid.knoxcountytn.gov/case-count.html):

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="cases_table"></table>
```

(I deleted the table body here because it is long), and I need a way of getting the data inside of it.

Both of these have returned none:

```py
table=soup.findAll('table', {'id': 'cases_table'})
table = soup.select('table#cases_table')
```

And this:

```py
table=soup.findAll('tbody')
```

returns one tbody that is not the tbody I'm looking for.

I also tried using this:

```py
table = soup.find_all('table')[x]
```

When x is 0, I get a table that I'm not looking for. When x is 1, I get an index is out of range error.

I have tried using lxml, html5lib, and the html.parser, but none of them have changed this.

If there is any other effective way of solving this problem (I'm trying to get the active cases on this website as the State does not publish it daily and Johns Hopkins doesn't have it either), please let me know.

P.S. I think that the problem lies with the requests module, as when I just download the page with the requests command to a text file, that section is missing as well.

Comment: Do you want to get all the data in the table?

Comment: That would be nice, but I really only need the active cases (or the recovered cases for that matter, they are interchangeable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source code of the page,you wouldn't see this element `<table class="table table-striped" id="cases_table"></table>`.It use `ajax` to load it.But you could get the data directly:

```
import requests
import csv, io

url = "https://covid.knoxcountytn.gov/includes/covid_cases.csv"

content_of_csv = requests.get(url).text

for i in csv.reader(io.StringIO(content_of_csv)):
    if i[0] == "Number of Active Cases":
        print("The number: " + i[1], "Percent: " + i[2])
```

Result:

```
The number: 2192 Percent: 42.70%
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly! I'm very new to how websites work, and I din't know/think to look in the covid_tables.js files (I see where those URLs are now).

Comment: @maxbear123 You could use Developer tools, Press F12 -> Network -> XHR to see the ajax request in Chrome.